# Can I override an event listener temporarily?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to add an event listener for the whole document, and another if the program is inside a function.

eg.

```
$(document).click(function(){
    foo();
    //etc.
});


function f1(){
   $(document).click(function(){
      bar();
      //etc.
   });

   //etc.
};
```

And when running:

```
 click -> foo(); 
 click -> foo();
  ...
 f1();
 click -> bar();
 click -> bar();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that it's OK to remove all `click` event handlers from `document`, you could use [`.off()`](http://api.jquery.com/off/) before attaching your new event:

```
$(document).click(foo);

function f1(){
   $(document).off('click').click(bar);
};
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/zququLyw/)

Answer (score 1):

A little late, but here is a some code which does what you want: [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3ko6mxvs/).

HTML:

```
<button id="f1" style="display:none;">Button for f1</button>
```

JS:

```
function f1() {
    $(document).off('click').on('click', foo);
}

var foo = function () {
    $('button').show().click(f2);
};

function f2(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    $(document).off('click', foo).on('click', bar);
}

var bar = function () {
    $('button').hide();
    f1();
};

f1();
```